# Send Whatsapp notification if SQL Server Agent Job fails

Tags: sql-server, notifications, whatsapp

I want to get a `whatsapp` notification if my job fails in SQL,I know how to send email notification but is it possible to send `whatsapp` notification to notify user that some error has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Never tested with whatsapp notifications, but it worked perfectly with SMS notifications, following are the summarized steps to achieve what your looking for.

1. Register a API gateway (if do not have already) with anyone of [service provider](https://chat-api.com/en/) (SMS/WhatsApp)
2. Create an [Ole Automation Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ole-automation-procedures-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017), your service provider API has to be compatible with Ole Automation Procedure, you may check/test it with API documentation
3. Create a new step (within SQL Job) that calls procedure (created in step2) and make it fire upon previous step failure or you may use **Alert** to call the procedure but it would be bit complex to apply desired logic.